# Why did Allah gave powers to the angels and jinns, but not to humans?

Tags: jinn, malaikah

I'm wondering why Allah swt gave powers to angels and jinns like teleporting to other places, and turning into animals or other things. But he did not granted us human beings those powers. Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: Who are we to discuss Allah's Will.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Best answer in the form of a comment, and I will add your answer after my answer as we are no one to question the will of Allah, glorified and exalted he is above any human or jinn intellect.

Answer (score 0):

Allah wishes whomever he gives power. He gave some powers to the prophets. Humans and jinns have the freewill but the angels don't have that. Angels are 100% obliged to Allah. They don't have freewill. Humans are the best creation of Allah (SWT). If you do good deeds you are superior to other creations of Allah and if you do bad deeds you're inferior. Allah can give powers anyone he wills.

Jazakallah Khairan

Comment: "Humans are the best creation of Allah (SWT)" - Can you give a reference for your claim?

Comment: @Ahmed One of the reasons for that is the sending of Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) in humans. Allah says in the Qur'an that "We have not sent you [O Mohammad] but as a mercy for **all of the worlds**. Clearly, a creation of Allah that is mercy to both, the heavens and the earth would be the greatest of all creations, and this creation of Allah was sent among humans.

Because of this, most scholars reach the conclusion that humans are the best creation of Allah, because Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) was sent amongst us.

Answer (score 0):

**Allah has given power to all of his creations**

What do you mean by power ? The meaning of power can vary from anything from strength to electricity.

As I understand it , Allah has given power to all of us.

For this context, I will only take Jinn and Men, as angels are irrelevant as they have no free will. Allah has given different powers to men and jinn.

> To Jinns He has given strength of the body

> And to Men He has given intellect of the mind.

A man is more intelligence than a jinn. An adult Jinn is like a Human baby when it comes to intelligence. Jinns do stuff like Teleportation and Transfiguration by their Strength of Body .

Humans are the best of Allah's creations because we have a higher intelligence than Jinns so we can utilise our free will to a great extent. We have transformed the surface of the Earth  ! Can Jinns build houses and buildings  ? Can they build rockets and aeroplanes ?

NO!

Have you ever wondered why Iblis was jealous of Adam  ?  He was jealous because Adam was more intelligent than him! Adam may have had a far inferior body than that of Iblis but his intelligence was a thousand fold better!

> When Allah created Adam, He taught him everything. Then Allah showed the angels,Iblis and Adam some objects. Allah asked them to tell the names of the objects. The angels didn't know ! Iblis didn't know!  But Adam  ( Ali ) did!

And that's why we are the best of Allah's creation  !

Allah knows best.

Comment: "Humans are the best of Allah's creations ..." - Can you provide a reference for your claim?

Comment: @Ahmed One of the reasons for that is the sending of Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) in humans. Allah says in the Qur'an that "We have not sent you [O Mohammad] but as a mercy for **all of the worlds**. Clearly, a creation of Allah that is mercy to both, the heavens and the earth would be the greatest of all creations, and this creation of Allah was sent among humans.

Because of this, most scholars reach the conclusion that humans are the best creation of Allah, because Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) was sent amongst us.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan Prophet Muhammed (SAW) was sent for both humankind and jinn kind. There are references to this in many Hadiths.

Comment: @Ahmed Yes I know but that only supports my statement more. That someone who was sent as a Prophet for all beings and a mercy for all the worlds (earth, heavens, and whatever that is between them) must be in the best of the species. That is actually the reason humans are the best creation of Allah, because of Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) being amongst us. Had there been a greater creation, Allah would've sent him (PBUH) in that species.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan "Had there been a greater creation, Allah would've sent him (PBUH) in that species." ... sorry but then by that logic even the Jinn are included and that would nullify your claim. Moreover, in the Quran, Allah states he has blessed Humans over "most of His Creations" ... if you get a chance look into the tafsir of Quran 17:70 ... it is matter of ghaib for us.  Therefore it is better for a us to adhere to that which is mentioned in the texts and not go beyond that. Barakallah fi :)

Comment: @Ahmed What do you mean that even Jinn are included? The Prophet (PBUH) was sent for the entire universe, the heavens, earths, and whatever that resides in or between them. IF THE PROHPET (PBUH) is a blessing for all of the worlds, which means whatever Allah had or will create then why is it so hard for someone to understand that he would be sent amongst the best species? The Prophet (PBUH) was sent **amongst** humans and **as a human** but as a Prophet **for** all creations, and he was a blessing for everything and everyone, even including angels.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan " The Prophet (PBUH) was sent for the entire universe, the heavens, earths, and whatever that resides in or between them. " , "The Prophet was sent amongst humans and as a human but as a Prophet for all creations, and he was a blessing for everything and everyone, even including angels" ... Brother again you are making several claims without any evidence. There is a lot of more to the universe than those reside on our planet. And I'm not even sure why you included angels. I'm not here to argue. I pray inshallah that you get the time to read into the tafsir for more details.

Comment: @Ahmed Brother, did you read my answer fully? I gave my evidence in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamoalikum.

There is no such thing as "power" without "knowledge". I am gonna use these Quranic verse to back my upcoming claims.

**He said, 'O Council, which one of you will bring me her throne, before they come to me in surrender?' [Quran 27:38] An Ifrit of the jinns said, 'I will bring it to thee, before thou risest from thy place; I have strength for it [Quran 27:39] and I am trusty.' Said he who possessed knowledge of the Book, 'I will bring it to thee, before ever thy glance returns to thee.' Then, when he saw it settled before him, he said, 'This is of my Lord's bounty that He may try me, whether I am thankful or ungrateful. Whosoever gives thanks gives thanks only for his own soul's good, and whosoever is ungrateful -- my Lord is surely All-sufficient, All-generous.' [Quran 27:40] He said, 'Disguise her throne for her, and we shall behold whether she is guided or if she is of those that are not guided.' [Quran 27:41] So, when she came, it was said, 'Is thy throne like this?' She said, 'It seems the same.' 'And we were given the knowledge before her, and we were in surrender, [Quran 27:42]**

It says in these verses that a strong Jinn said he was able to bring the throne of Queen of Sheeba before Suleiman (AS) gets up from his throne. On the other hand, a man, a human, who had **knowledge** from the scriptures said **"I will bring it to you before the blink of your eye."**

This man according to scholars was known as Asif Ibn Barkhiya, who was a Muslim but **not a Prophet**.

We learned from this Ayah that Allah blesses his certain servants with **knowledge** of certain things, that we normal people consider as Karamaat (Miracles, but done by a non-prophet). **They don't get Wahih** (direct revelation from Allah or his angels) but they simply discover the way to do it by the will and blessings of Allah.

So this proves that there is some knowledge not known to normal humans which do allow humans to do things far superior to Jinns, **and are only given to either Prophets of Allah or his blessed servants**.

However, the actual reason Jinns can do these things without any special knowledge sent to them from Allah is because they are solely energy, as mentioned by Allah that they are created by the purest fire. Energy can transform into any state, that is the reason Jinns can travel at higher speeds, are physically stronger than us.

On the other hand, humans are both, matter and energy, we have a **defined state** that we cannot bypass unless by the will of Allah and blessed knowledge from him.

As for the angels, they are not for comparison as they do not fall under the classifications of what can be explained by us, energy or matter. They are instead made by Noor (light) and we don't know much about the light that angels are made of **BUT** they act according to the commandments of Allah, they do exactly and specifically what Allah orders them to do, not more not less, so it would be clear that these "powers" and whatnot is provided to them directly by Allah to carry out whatever tasks they have been assigned with.

We, humans, are the best creation of Allah because Allah sent Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) among us. And Allah says in the Qur'an,

**And We have not sent you but as mercy for all the worlds. [Quran 21:107]**

If the Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) is a mercy for all the worlds (Heavens, earth, Jinns, angels, mankind, **all that Allah has made**) then it **must be** that he would be the best of the creation, and this best of the creation is sent among humans.

**If the best creation and mercy to all the worlds is sent amongst humans then humans are the best species.**

At last, I would like to state what @MediSaif said, which is **"Who are we to discuss the will of Allah?"** he is far exalted above the understanding of human intellect, he is the all-wise all-knower.

**Allah knows the best.**

Comment: There is no power and no strength except with Allah (Sunan Ibn Majah)

Comment: @ahmadnazeem Yes I agree, but how is it relevant to my answer?